# Reading keyboard input ASM

Tags: assembly, mips, mars-simulator

I want to take the input from the MARS Keyboard simulator.
When the user doesn't enter a character I want to print out "Please, enter a character...".

If he does enter a character, I want to output that character once.

This is my code:

```
#MIPS
#ND
#2 a

.data
    text:   .asciiz "Please enter a character...\n"
.text

j print
main:
        lw $t0, 0xffff0000  #t1 holds if input available

    li $a0, 2000    #Time to sleep (milliseconds)

    li $v0, 32  #Operation code for sleeping
    syscall

    beq $t0, 0, print   #If no input is typed in, goto print (else printIn)


printIn:        #Printing input
    li $v0, 4
    lw $a0, 0xffff0004
    syscall

    j main

print:      #Printing text asking for input
    la $a0, text
    li $v0, 4
    syscall

    j main
```

My code is working, until I enter a character in the keyboard simulator, than I get this error at runtime:

```
line 24: Runtime exception at 0x0040002c: address out of range 0x00000065
```

I really searched but really can't see what's wrong with my code...
It's MIPS ASM by the way, and this information can be helpful as well:
[image: mips keyboard]

Comment: The problem is the printing, not the reading. As you know, syscall #4 expects a pointer. So you need to store the character in memory and pass its address.

Comment: Or use [syscall #11 "print character"](http://courses.missouristate.edu/kenvollmar/mars/help/syscallhelp.html)

Comment: @Jester I tried several instructions and ways to do it, but I can't seem to figure out the steps storing in memory and passing the address...

Comment: reserve some memory, like in `.data` add `inputChar: .byte 0, 0` (second zero will work as string terminator for v0=4 syscall) .. then after `lw $a0, 0xffff0004` store the byte value into memory `sb $a0, inputChar` and then use that memory address as argument for syscall: `la $a0, inputChar`

Comment: @Ped7g Thanks a lot!!